# How to create and use same class in main C# code and runtime compiled code?

Tags: c#, .net

My C# app uses `CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource` to compile small scripts on C#.

I need a way to set many fields of main code in script.

I need something that will be visible in both places.

I declared test class in script and main code like that:

```
namespace MainNS
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string asd;
        public int dsa;
    }
}
```

My script looks like that:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ScriptedNS
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string asd;
        public int dsa;
    }

    public class ScriptTaskInfo
    {
        private TestClass GlobalTC;     

        public void Initialize(object global_tc)
        {
            this.GlobalTC = (TestClass)global_tc; //of course invalid cast here
            this.GlobalTC.asd = "string set from script that should be visible in main code";
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            //do something with this.GlobalTC
        }
    }
}
```

When I create `TestClass` instance in main code and try to `Initialize` script object with it I getting invalid cast exception.

How to achieve that same object is visible for both script and main code and I can set it's fields like normal, not just having `Dictionary<string, object>` map and always casting from object to different types.

Answer (score 0):

instead of (object global_tc) you can use (dynamic global_tc)

```
public class ScriptTaskInfo
    {
        private TestClass GlobalTC;     

        public void Initialize(dynamic global_tc)
        {
            this.GlobalTC = global_tc; 
            this.GlobalTC.asd = "string set from script that should be visible in main code";
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            //do something with this.GlobalTC
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I changed `object` to `dynamic` my script is not able to compile anymore. The error is: `Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute'`.

I tried to add "using System.Runtime.CompilerServices" but it didn't solve the error.